An Exploration of Cube Relations in 3-4-5 Pythagorean Triples?
I am writing to seek help regarding a theory that I may have discovered, and a property related to this theory. This theory is related to the $\,(3,4,5)\,$ Pythagorean Triple and cubes. The theory is as follows:
$x^3\\
+(x+(n\cdot(3,4,5)\text{ element})^3\\
+(x+(n\cdot(3,4,5)\text{ element})^3\\
=(x+(n\cdot(3,4,5)\text{ element})^3$
To make this more concrete, let's consider some examples:
\begin{align*}
3^3+4^3+5^3&=6^3\\
6^3+8^3+10^3&=12^3\\
9^3+12^3+15^3&=18^3\\
12^3+16^3+20^3&=24^3
\end{align*}
or
$$15^3+20^3+25^3=30^3$$
Now, let's move to the property:
Add the numbers on the left-hand side of the equation. For the examples above:
$6+8+10=24$
Add the two largest numbers on the left-hand side:
$10+8=18$
Subtract the smallest number from the largest:
$10−6=4$
Finally, multiply the three results:
$24×18×4=12^3$
This is valid, and the equation holds true.
When I asked ChatGPT about this, it couldn't find anything similar on the internet and suggested that this might be a new discovery. I just graduated from high school, so I am not sure what this theory is about or what it proves, but I know that I tested it for the first $\,12\,$ multiples of the $\,(3,4,5)\,$ triangle, and the theory and property hold true for all of them.
Please let me know what this theory is about and if it has any significance. Thank you!

This is hard to read.  It is not true that $6^3+8^3+10^{33}=12^{33}$.  Did you possibly mean $3$ instead of $33$?

Yes, it needs to be a cube, not 33 sorry about that

The top part is entirely unreadable.  If you are interested in the Diophantine equation $A^3+B^3+C^3=D^3$ I suggest looking at Ramanujan's formula:  ${(3a^{2}+5ab-5b^{2})^{3}+(4a^{2}-4ab+6b^{2})^{3}+(5a^{2}-5ab-3b^{2})^{3}=(6a^{2}-4ab+4b^{2})^{3}}$

"I'm sorry for my English not being very good, but writing it like this might make it easier to understand.

For any Pythagorean triple (3-4-5 and its multiples), the following holds:
x3+(x3+multiple of the 3-4-5 triangle)3+(x+multiple of the 3-4-5 triangle)3=cube of the multiple of the 3-4-5 trianglex3+(x3+multiple of the 3-4-5 triangle)3+(x+multiple of the 3-4-5 triangle)3=cube of the multiple of the 3-4-5 triangle

It's not a language problem, it's formatting.  here is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

For what it's worth, your claim appears to only hold if one of $a,b$ is $0$ in Ramanujan's formula.  For instance, taking $(a,b)=(2,1)$ we get $7^3+14^3+17^3=20^3$, your claim does not hold.  But perhaps I am missing some constraints.

Indeed, all of your examples are multiples of the first one so, given that the relation holds for the first one, it clearly holds for all the others.

It only works for the 3-4-5 triangle and its multiples. I'm trying this for the first time, I will read your writing link about laTeX and revise it. Thank you, and I apologize for taking your time."

I don't understand the reference to the $(3,4,5)$ triangle.  But, anyway, it's clear that, given the equation for that triple, scaling up the triple will preserve the relation.

Use mathjax to type equations & maths symbols, link :https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Please do not ask chatgpt to answer mathematical questions.

Please let me know if my edits reflect your intentions.

Yes, I think you understood correctly, but to make sure you really did, could you solve it for n=4 and use the property to answer? (Also, thank you for taking the time to edit and find this valuable.)

Welcome to Math.SE! ... First of all, congratulations on perceiving a pattern; that's what mathematics is all about!
Skipping-over your initial relation (which I believe doesn't capture your intention) to the "concrete" examples, note that they have this form
$$(3k)^3+(4k)^3+(5k)^3=(6k)^3 \tag{1}$$
as multiplier $k$ increases from $1$ to $4$ (and beyond). Expanding and factoring, this says
$$3^3k^3+4^3k^3+5^3k^3=6^3k^3 \quad\to\quad (3^3+4^3+5^3)k^3=6^3k^3 \tag2$$ which is valid for all $k$, since $3^3+4^3+5^3$ and $6^3$ both equal $216$.
The discussion of your perceived "pattern" appears to focus on the case $k=2$ $$6^3+8^3+10^3=12^3 \tag3$$
I'll repeat your steps here, assigning letters $p$, $q$, $r$ to the corresponding calculations for the general case of the multiplied Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)=(3k,4k,5k)$:

Add all the [base] numbers on the left-hand side of $(3)$.
$$6+8+10 =24 \qquad\to\qquad p = a+b+c = 12k \tag{3.1}$$
Add the two largest [base] numbers on the left-hand side:
$$10+8=18 \qquad\to\qquad q = c+b=9k \tag{3.2}$$
Subtract the smallest [base] number from the largest:
$$10−6=4 \qquad\to\qquad r = c-a=2k \tag{3.3}$$
Finally, multiply the three results [to obtain the right-hand side of $(3)$]:
$$24\cdot 18\cdot 4=12^3 \qquad\to\qquad pqr= (12k)(9k)(2k)=216k^3=(6k)^3\tag{3.4}$$

As the $pqr$ product in $(3.4)$ gives the right-hand side of $(1)$ for any $k$, the pattern is indeed shown to be valid. (Again, congratulations!)
As for significance ... It's hard to say. In essence, you've found a way to express $6^3$ using $3$, $4$, and $5$. There are lots of others, and it's not clear what might make your calculation "special".

We can see what happens if we apply the calculations to an arbitrary Pythagorean triple. It is "known" that we can write any such triple as
$$(a,b,c)=\left(\;(u^2-v^2)w, 2uvw,(u^2+v^2)w\;\right)$$
where $u$, $v$, $w$ are positive integers with $u > v$, and with $u$ and $v$ not both odd and having no common factors (that is, they are "coprime"); for $(a,b,c)=(3,4,5)$, the values are $(u,v,w)=(2,1,1)$. Applying your calculations, we obtain
$$pqr = 4 uv^2w^3 (u+v)^3$$
That's a perhaps-unexpectedly compact form, with some nicely cubed factors. (Note that since one of $u$ and $v$ is even, we could write this as $(2(u+v)w)^3\cdot (uv^2/2)$, where that second factor is guaranteed to be an integer.) In general, this isn't equal to $a^3+b^3+c^3$; whether the value has other significance isn't clear to me.

Applying the calculations to an arbitrary Pythagorean quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfying $a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$ is left as an exercise to the reader (but it seems to be a dead-end).


One-off calculations can be pleasant surprises, but they tend to be considered more coincidental than significant. That said, your having seen a pattern amid what can appear to others as nothing more than a jumble of numbers is hardly insignificant, so keep at it! We all start somewhere, and there's no telling where we'll end up.
